# Why is rc.local in /etc, should it be owned by root, and when is it run?

Tags: 12.04, server, bashrc

My understanding of `rc.local`, based on a quick Google search, is that I can put some bash in it which will be run at the beginning of [something] (what, user login, system start up?).

The `rc.local` in my Ubuntu 12.04.2 server is owned by my user, `orokusaki`, vs being owned by `root`. Because it's in `/etc`, I'm guessing it's more of a global thing vs a user-specific thing. Is this true? If so, why did Ubuntu create it with my `orokusaki` user, but then put it in `etc`? Should I `chown root:root /etc/rc.local` to fix it, or should I move it into my home directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Ubuntu 12.04, your rc.local should be owned by root. It's run by root, on startup.

You can `sudo -u <user> <command>` to run things as another user in rc.local, but I admit that in nearly every single case of using rc.local I've come across, I've found it far simpler to use Startup Programs instead.

I suppose your mileage may vary. I'm afraid I don't know why your rc.local is owned by your user.